# What is the origin of the throw/catch exception naming?

Tags: c++, exception

Was the creator of this construct a baseball fan?

Comment: Voting for close, "Was the creator of this construct a baseball fan?" is not a real question, or is not programming related.

Comment: i don't think this deserves a close. the question oviously was meant to be a joke. real question is in the title.

Comment: should definitely not be closed - reopening

Comment: although the base-baller probably has invented this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374945/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-baller-which-means-pointer haha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Stroustrup's book "The Design & Evolution of C++" - basically, "raise" was already taken.

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~frankel/TechRep/pdfs/TR-08-03.pdf

> MacLISP was first to introduce
>   catch/throw as an exception handling
>   mechanism for handling exceptional
>   conditions[9]
>   ...
>   [9]Moon, D. A. The MacLisp Reference Manual. MIT Project MAC, April 1974.

-Adam

Answer (score 4):

I don't know, but I recall that LISP had a THROW function back in '76 or so. You would throw a value out of some deeply-nested set of parentheses, and where it was caught, it would return that value.